# create 3D pie chart or 3D circle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I want to create a 3D pie chart.

Do I have to use OpenGl ES or Core Graphics?

How can I draw a 3D pie chart or at least a 3D circle?

Thank you for helping.

I want to create a dynamic chart, so I have to use objective c and xcode.

Each pie chart piece has to be treaten separately. I didn't find any library which I could use.

Comment: check out http://www.ivisualization.com/

Comment: Please note that 3D pie charts are **highly** [discouraged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_chart#3-D_pie_chart) since they actually distort the information that is being presented. Pie charts themselves are bad enough (other representations are always superior) but 3D pie charts are an abomination.

Comment: tried with ivisualization but i couldnt see a plain blank screen on the simulator.

Comment: hi ppl if you have found any lib for 3d pie charts,can you plz share it with me,thanks in adv.

Comment: Please refer to the video of the Citibank For iPad® app :
http://www.google.co.in/url?url=http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xk7yuz_citibank-for-ipad-app_news&rct=j&sa=U&ei=mmSvUI2eMcXtrQfymoDABQ&ved=0CCAQtwIwBA&sig2=WgmGP2A1IykQbnHNjNTZlA&q=citibank+for+ipad%C2%AE&usg=AFQjCNEwnXu8cO7ObOxRAFgiX-W3kJC7yA

@Konrad Rudolf :

Comment: @AbhishekBedi Why? The video is too long to watch and it seems irrelevant in this context.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - In the video -see the Screen : HOW PEOPLE SPEND MONEY, you can see 3D boxes made in CoreGraphics & OpenGL. I mentioned the link so that we can see the outcome of using these frameworks/libraries. :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely 3D pie charts can be created using OPENGLES.

Refer to : [Ray's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)

And just you wanna see the REAL implemention: [Citibank For iPad® Video](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @LithuT.V :Link Updated For Opengled Tute.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably using [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html).

Here is an example:

[image: 3D Pie Chart]

The URL for this is https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=250x100&chd=t:20,30,50&chl=a|b|c

So you would download the image and display it in an UIImageView.

Comment: I want to create a dynamic 3D pie chart, so i have to use objective c and xcode.

Comment: There are commercial libs for this if you don't want to roll your own. Example: http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/ioschart/

Comment: I see only 2D pie charts in the examples of IOS charts

Comment: The Google Chart API require throughout connectivity. You can make 3D graphs using OPengES or CoreGraphics. OPengles will be tough.
Refer to : [http://www.google.co.in/url?url=http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial&rct=j&sa=U&ei=umWvULOkIIyQrgean4G4DA&ved=0CBQQFjAA&sig2=COZk7RpJfse6t_BPzqEPzA&q=ray+opengles2&usg=AFQjCNEIYXh2oMxqHqTm34wjhkLmpCyxZg].